# JqueryUI sortable, draggable and droppable, does not sort while new element is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have read examples and different solutions but yet i am stuck with my code. Target is to make it work so that one can drag elements (green in fiddle) to target area, where other element is added to target area (pdiv) and dragged element reverts back to its position to be used again. Also dragged element could be sorted while dragged in wanted place.

Now i can drag and drop elements and sort them in place. How do i enable sortable while dragging new element? Also list must be sortable all times, which kind of works but now it runs append code also when sorting.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

html

```
<div id="pdiv"></div>
<div id="htmldivi">
<div class="element" value="text">For text</div>
<div class="element" value="img">For Image</div>
<div class="element" value="2 img">For 2 Image</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.element {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#0C3;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:4px;
}

#pdiv {
    width:500px;
    min-height:100px;
    top:110px;
    border:2px solid;
    }   

.vali {
    height: 15px;
    background-color:#ffe58f;
    border:2px dotted #0C0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    width:99%;
    margin-left:2px;
}

.fortest {
    background-color:#eae1c3;

}
```

script

```
$(function() {
    $( ".element" ).draggable({ connectWith: "#pdiv",revert: true, helper: "clone" });
    $( "#pdiv" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
          var type = ui.draggable.attr("value");
        $.ajax({
            success : function (data) {
                var valuessi = (ui.draggable.attr("value"));
                $("#pdiv").append('<div class="fortest">' + valuessi + '</div>');
            }
        });
      }
    });
  });


$(function() {  
  $( "#pdiv" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "vali"
    });
    $( "#pdiv" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Here it is in fiddle. [Jquery draggable, droppable and sortable](http://jsfiddle.net/2j89q886/)

Comment: Ajax is there, because later on there will be things done in it.